# How to kill a thread sending long running HTTP request?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following Task class which sends http request to the API. In case the process takes too long time, I want to kill the Thread by calling the stop function, however it is not working.

```
class Task implements Runnable{

        private final AtomicReference<Thread> currentThread = new AtomicReference<Thread>();
        private String bid;
        private long id;

        public Task(String bid, long id) {
            this.bid = bid;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            currentThread.set(Thread.currentThread());
            // send http request
            String result = service.checkPaymentState(id, bid);
        }

        public void stop() {
            System.out.println("stop!!!");
            currentThread.get().interrupt();
        }
    }
```

Main method. Task should be cancelled if it does not finish within 2 seconds:

```
Task task = new Task(bid, id);
Future future = taskScheduler.submit(task);

scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> {
            if (!future.isDone()) {
                System.out.println("Cancelled!");
                future.cancel(true);
                task.stop();
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Can you also please show the code where you create, run and stop the task from another thread?

Comment: and usually, instead of an interrupt, you should stop the long running task, i.e. the `service.checkPaymentState` should also provide a stop function - at least that would be the cleanest way

Comment: @AKSW yes, it is from another thread, I have added the code. How can I stop `service.checkPaymentState` method? it is just sending a HTTP request

Answer (score 3):

Interrupt thread that was got from ThreadPool - is bad idea - you dont know thread pool *interruption policy*. One day you can change implementation of thread pool to one that do not create new thread - when some of worker thread is interrupted and killed - eventually you will run out of thread in thread pool.

Preferred way is to call `future.cancel(true);` - You will get `InterruptedException` - on long running HTTP request.

NOTE: do not catch `InterruptedException` and swallow - let it be handled on the thread pool level and interruption policy applied. Or if swallow it - set interruption flag manually on the thread by `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the code as follows:

1. Invoke `taskScheduler.shutdown()` after you submit the task. Otherwise your *ExecutorService* will hang waiting for new *Tasks* and won't let *JVM* shutdown gracefully.
2. If you want your *Thread* to return value after it finishes implement *Callable* instead
3. As @Oleksandr Papchenko said:

> do not interrupt *Thread* that was got from *ThreadPool*

In your example - do not store the reference to pool's *Thread* and interrupt it in your `stop()` method. You can redo `run()` as follows:

```
public String call() {
         try {
           /*
            * describe logic of your service.checkPaymentState(id, bid) here
            * if you have blocking methods wrap them in a try-catch block
           */
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Save the interrupted status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return null;
         }
         return value;
    }
```

4. Remove `stop()` method and simply do `future.cancel(true)` in the `scheduledExecutorService`
5. If you do not have blocking methods inside `call()` you should elaborate your own interruption policy. For example, if working with sockets for interruption call `socket.close()` outside and implement interruption inside *SocketException* catch clause.